# How can I select ONLY the nearest value less-than the 'target' value?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to filter historic Betfair data.
I want to get one record for each item in `FULL_DESCRIPTION`.
The SQL I'm using gives me several records per item, each having a different `LATEST_TAKEN`.
`LATEST_TAKEN` is already filtered to give values less than `DT ACTUAL_OFF` (both are date/time). 
I've looked at other postings but my capability levels don't match my enthusiasm.

I'm currently using:

```
SELECT Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.*
FROM Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439
WHERE (((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.FULL_DESCRIPTION) Like "English Soccer/Barclays Premier League*") 
    AND ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.LATEST_TAKEN) < [DT ACTUAL_OFF]) 
    AND ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.SPORTS_ID)="1") 
    AND ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.EVENT)="Correct Score") 
    AND ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.IN_PLAY)="pe"))
ORDER BY Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.EVENT_ID, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.FULL_DESCRIPTION, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.SELECTION, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.LATEST_TAKEN DESC;
```

This leaves me with multiple records per item whereas I only want the record whose `LATEST_TAKEN` value is closest to that of `DT ACTUAL_OFF`

Answer (score 0):

So taking your query, I just changed the order in the ORDER BY clause so LATEST_TAKEN was the first sort parameter. Then I added a LIMIT 1 so it only returned one result. I think this should return what you're looking for

```
SELECT
    Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.*
FROM
    Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439
WHERE
    (((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.FULL_DESCRIPTION) Like "English Soccer/Barclays Premier League*") AND
    ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.LATEST_TAKEN)<[DT ACTUAL_OFF]) AND
    ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.SPORTS_ID)="1") AND
    ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.EVENT)="Correct Score") AND
    ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.IN_PLAY)="pe"))
ORDER BY
    Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.LATEST_TAKEN DESC,
    Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.EVENT_ID,
    Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.FULL_DESCRIPTION,
    Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.SELECTION
LIMIT 1;
```

I have simplified matters for clarity:

```
SELECT   
Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.FULL_DESCRIPTION, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.SELECTION, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.ODDS, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.LATEST_TAKEN
FROM Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439   
WHERE   
(((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.SPORTS_ID)="1") AND ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.EVENT)="Correct Score") AND ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.IN_PLAY)="pe") AND ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.FULL_DESCRIPTION) Like "English Soccer/Barclays Premier League*") AND ((Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.LATEST_TAKEN)<[DT ACTUAL_OFF]))  
ORDER BY    
Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.EVENT_ID, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.FULL_DESCRIPTION, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.SELECTION, Bfinf_other_150126to150201_150204124439.LATEST_TAKEN DESC;
```

Gives:

FULL_DESCRIPTION    -    SELECTION   -   ODDS    -   LATEST_TAKEN

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 0   9.2 31-01-2015 12:34:52

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 0   9.8 28-01-2015 03:09:13

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 0   10.5    25-01-2015 19:19:35

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 0   9.4 24-01-2015 11:51:58

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 1   9.2 31-01-2015 12:45:05

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 1   9.6 31-01-2015 12:00:57

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 1   9   31-01-2015 11:50:25

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 1   8.8 30-01-2015 18:26:06

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 2   16  31-01-2015 12:45:05

English Soccer/Barclays Premier League/Fixtures 31 January  /Hull v Newcastle   0 - 2   16.5    31-01-2015 12:43:22

I require rows 1,5 and 9
I.E. For each match (FULL_DESCRIPTION) the correct score(SELECTION) ODDS at the greatest time (LATEST_TAKEN) before the start of the event ([DT ACTUAL_OFF).

Comment: Thanks Frank.This gives the error message:Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'Bfinf_other150126to150201_150204124439.SELECTION LIMIT !'.

Comment: I think changing the ORDER BY clause will not work as FULL_DESCRIPTION has several SELECTION's and each SELECTION has it's own LATEST_TAKEN (which is date/time and must be the closest to DT ACTUAL_OFF)

Comment: EVENT_ID DT ACTUAL_OFF FULL_DESCRIPTION SELECTION LATEST_TAKEN
1  9:00  RUN   1  8:55
1  9:00  RUN   2  8:50
1  9:00  RUN   3  8:00
2  10:30  Jump   1  10:29
2  10:30  Jump   5  10:20  
2  10:30  Jump   4  10:15

My desired return is the first and fourth record.

Comment: I think the answer lies along the lines of:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1   So I'm playing around with that.